# (spring) DI にて、 main 引数など java の値を inject するには？

Tags: java, spring

今現在、 spring を用いて開発しています。
context.xml の中で、 constructor-arg などを用いて、java の値(eg. String)を inject できることは理解したのですが、たとえば main 関数の引数の値を inject したい場合などには、どのようにしたらこれを行なえるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132231/dealing-with-command-line-arguments-and-spring)のページの転載にはなりますが、次の2つの方法があるようです。

1. コマンドライン引数をstatic変数に入れて、SpringのBeanから参照する
2. コマンドライン引数をBeanFactoryに登録して、それをアプリケーションコンテキストに反映する

1の例です。次のようなクラスがあるとします。

```
public class MyApp {
  public static String[] ARGS; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      ARGS = args;
      // 通常のアプリケーションコンテキスト作成コード
  }
}
```

このstatic変数は次のような設定で使用できます。

```
<util:constant static-field="MyApp.ARGS"/>
```

2の例です。

```
public class MyApp2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();

    // Beanを定義してコンテキストに登録する
    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = BeanDefinitionBuilder
        .rootBeanDefinition(Arrays.class, "asList")
        .addConstructorArgValue(args).getBeanDefinition();
    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("args", beanDefinition);
    GenericApplicationContext cmdArgCxt = new GenericApplicationContext(beanFactory);
    // 必ずrefreshを呼び出し、コンテキストを初期化する
    cmdArgCxt.refresh();

    // 設定ファイルと今作成したコンテキストから新しいアプリケーションコンテキストを作成する
    ApplicationContext mainContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml", cmdArgCxt);

    // Beanとしてコマンドライン引数を参照する
    System.out.println("Args: " + mainContext.getBean("args"));
  }

}
```